# Android activity has too many lines

Tags: android, android-activity, optimization

I'm working on an Android Studio project. 
One of the Activities is a form with 50 EditTexts.
Since there are so many EditTexts, the Activity's file has over 1200 lines and should have another 300 - 400 more once completed. 
It has become difficult and time-consuming to navigate the code in the file.

Are there any standards I should follow for this situation? 
What would be the best course of actions now?

Comment: I would start by not having 50 `EditText` widgets on a single screen. When you divide that up (e.g., into wizard pages or something), that in turn will tend to divide up the code (e.g., into fragments that go into those wizard pages).

Comment: Databinding can reduce the number of views in your acitivity by translating then to a model that has 50 fields, if they are a list so you need to use a List component such RecyclerView, another thing that consume lines is having all kind of logics inside of your activity, for example opening a cursor from sqlite and parsing the result, that routines should be extracted to a especialized class that you can simple use on your activity.

Comment: Extracting AsyncTasks and JSON/XML parsers too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use RecyclerView if you have so many edit texts.
Go through it -

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 5):

This really isn't an answer. but I didn't have enough room in the comments.

1) 50 edit texts alone is a big no no. Try to split that up into section where a user can navigate from fragment to fragment as they fill the form out.

2) If you want to keep everything on one activity then write a method that you can collapse. For example, I assume you have 50 lines of code for the instantiating the edit texts. Put that into a method at the bottom and call the method in your on create.

3) Piggy backing off of number 2... Create methods for code that you are repeating over and over again. Creating a method will allow you to collapse it into one line while all the code is inside of that method. It will make reading your code easier. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Try using #region ... #endregion